# uniq two array objects and give priority to true value

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I am trying to do array manipulations inside an arrays object as shown below:

```
var first = [{
    a: "one",
    x: false
}, {
    a: "two",
    x: true
}, {
    a: "three",
    x: false
}, {
    a: "one",
    x: true
}, {
    a: "two",
    x: true
}, {
    a: "four",
    x: false
}];
```

Expected result:

```
// Result
[{
    a: "one",
    x: true
}, {
    a: "two",
    x: true
}, {
    a: "three",
    x: false
}, {
    a: "four",
    x: false
}];
```

As you can see, I am trying to omit the duplicates which have the same value for the key `a` but also before omitting that object, I want to compare among other duplicates and push the object which has true value for key `x` (*if there are no true values available, then I will push the `x: false` value only*).

I am open to use `lodash` or `underscore` to achieve this.

I tried using `_.unionBy` and `_.uniqBy` but I am unable to understand on how to consider `x: true` properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lodash.

Group by attribute `a`. Then merge objects inside each group; keep only truthy values.

```js
let array = [
    {a: 'one', x: false},
    {a: 'two', x: true},
    {a: 'three', x: false},
    {a: 'one', x: true},
    {a: 'two', x: true},
    {a: 'four', x: false},
];

let result = _(array)
    .groupBy('a')
    .map(objects => _.mergeWith(...objects, (a, b) => a || b))
    .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = [];

first.forEach(f => {
   var index = results.map(r => r.a).indexOf(f.a);

   if(index === -1) {
      results.push(f)
   } else {
      f.x && (results[index].x = true);
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var unique = _.uniqWith(first, _.isEqual);
var result = unique.filter((item) => {
    if (item.x) return true;
    var sameA = unique.filter((i) => i.a === item.a);
    return sameA.length === 1;
});
```